# Escape sequence in a string literal (Fortran)

Tags: string, fortran, escaping

There is an example in C++

```
string str;
str = "First\n"
      "Second\n"
      "Third;\n";
cout << str << endl;
```

The output will be

```
First
Second
Third;
```

I wanna try to repeat it in Fortran and didn't find any info about escape-sequence in char string like in C++.

Comment: Your example code is C++, not C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use [`achar`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ACHAR.html) with the ASCII code for *linefeed*, that is `10`. The advantage of this method is, you can use other characters as necessary if you know the ASCII code.

```
character(len=32):: str = "First" // achar(10) // "Second"
```

Gives you the desired result. (Note: `//` is the character concatenation operator)

The other would be to replace `achar(10)` with `new_line('a')` and that works only for inserting linefeeds.

Interestingly, if you're using `gfortran`, you can use the option `-fbackslash` while compiling to use C-style backslashing, as mentioned in the documentation:

> -fbackslash
>
> Change the interpretation of backslashes in string literals from a single backslash character to “C-style” escape characters. The following combinations are expanded \a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \v, \, and \0 to the ASCII characters alert, backspace, form feed, newline, carriage return, horizontal tab, vertical tab, backslash, and NUL, respectively. Additionally, \xnn, \unnnn and \Unnnnnnnn (where each n is a hexadecimal digit) are translated into the Unicode characters corresponding to the specified code points. All other combinations of a character preceded by \ are unexpanded.

Thus, the string would simplify to

```
str = "First\nSecond"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use [`new_line()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NEW_005fLINE.html#NEW_005fLINE) intrinsic and `//` concatenation operator:

```
program main
  implicit none
  character(128) :: str
  character      :: NL = new_line("a")

  str = "first"//NL//"second"//NL//"third"
  write (*,"(a)") str

end program main
```

Comment: thnx for the answer,  but it platform-specific solution. For example, it doesn't work on OpenVMS OS

Comment: That's because (as I understand it) OpenVMS doesn't support a reasonably up to date Fortran compiler. Newline has been part of the standard from F2003 I think.